# localForage finds Data in Chrome, Not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, localforage

I am getting some peculiar behavior in Firefox with localForage. I set up a page to load two arrays using the standard 'setItem' form:

```
 <script src="localforage.js"></script>
 <body>
<script>
var data = [1,2,3,4,5];
localforage.setItem("saveData", data, function(err, value) {
if (err) {
 console.error('error: ', err);
} else {    
console.log("Data Saved");
}});

localforage.getItem("saveData", function (err, value) {
if (err) {
   console.error('error: ', err);
} else {
    console.log('saveData is: ', value);
    localforage.keys(function(err, keys) {
    console.log("Keys: " + keys);
    console.log("Number of keys: " + keys.length);
    });
}});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The array was saved correctly.

I then made a second page, using exactly the same "getItem" function.

In Chrome, the data showed up, but in Firefox it was not listed at all, and could not be opened.

Has anyone else experienced this? In Firefox, even opening the second page in the same session fails to find the saved file. I have tried changing security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy, but it made no difference.

I would rather use Firefox, but I can't if it keeps losing saved data.

Comment: Could you please show us the actual code or at least a simplified example to reproduce the error

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue but solved it after some researching, trials and discussions. Extensions like FireStorage Plus! and simple session storage do not work flawlessly for detecting this data, especially if it is being performed on a page/file other than the original root page/file.

The solution for me was to use the native FF Storage Inspector. Only then could I see ALL of the data I was missing. Those extensions did not show the data, even though it was being set.

Refer to: [localForage setItem/getItem unreliable in Firefox / FireStorage Plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482778/localforage-setitem-getitem-unreliable-in-firefox-firestorage-plus)

[image]

In addition, **for future assistance with localForage issues, try their IRC chat** **#localforage** at https://webchat.freenode.net/ and look for **tofumatt**. He is the guru you want to confer with. ^5

Comment: Thank you for this. However, I am getting "No data present for selected host," which suggests that the data is not being set in the first place. I am a little confused about this, as I thought LocalForage was designed for Firefox...

Comment: I am not even seeing data after using an iteration like the .keys method, and this is on the same page/file. Not sure if it is related, but seems to have something to do with the scope being used.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634613/localforage-keys-method-variable-data-not-seen-outside-of-method

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this from `file://` as opposed to `http://`? I believe in Firefox you cannot access IndexedDB if you open an HTML page from `file://`. So in this case you would need to run an HTTP server – easiest way is to do `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` and then go to `http://localhost:8080`. Chrome might be different.

Comment: Actually just tested in Firefox, seems `file://` works now. :/ If you can provide more details, that would help elucidate.

Comment: I am using it from file://, as I wanted a convenient way to store data from a scheduling application I am developing. It just seems that the data I save from one page is invisible to any other page: in the Firefox Storage Inspector, as mentioned above, I just get "No data present for selected host." I have not tried using it with an HTTP servers, as I didn't (yet) need to get into configuring servers -- I just wanted a reliable source of persistent storage.

Comment: As I said, it works flawlessly with Chrome, and I have made sure that Firefox is running without extensions which might interfere, but data saved by one page is invisible to any other.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the browser data/cache/history? Sometimes browsers just get into weird states. You might also try serving from a different URL to see what happens, or try FirefoxDeveloperEdition for a second opinion.