# localForage setItem/getItem unreliable in Firefox / FireStorage Plus

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, localforage

I am loading a local instance of localForage and using it with Promise chains to save basic data. A simple example:

```
localforage.getItem("sellerExtension").then(function(sellerExtension) {
if ((!sellerExtension)  || (sellerExtension.length < 3)) {
    var sellerExtension = $('input#sellerExtension').val();
    if ((sellerExtension)  && (sellerExtension.length > 3)) {
        localforage.setItem('sellerExtension', sellerExtension).then( function() {

        });
    }
} 
});
```

The problem comes **when I go into the FF Dev-Tools to check FireStorage Plus! and see nothing related to the saved/set data. BUT I do in Chrome just fine.** There should be several saved items.

I'd been replacing localStorage (just for Firefox ugh) and am somewhat perplexed why thier own wrapper isn't showing in this FF specific extension for accessing the local DB instances. It shows key, getItem, clear and all, however.

Any ideas why this is happening? I fully expected to see something, and am looking in the right spot, I believe. (Screenshot below) **It doesn't seem to be loading the data from a .getItem request, either.**

I am using some AJAX to access other files in a sub-directory which handles localForage, but am on the same domain/port. Could I somehow be working in another scope? How would I know?

Thanx MUCH for any assistance!

[image]

And in Chrome I see it all...

[image]

BUT not in FF in any of the Scopes listed...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Could the problem be that it's `localStorage` and not `localForage` as you have in your code?**

Did you notice that in your screen shot, the Firebug tab says **localStorage** on it?

Comment: It does not matter what Tab I am on, session, all scopes, both... the data is not there in any tab, Scott. Yeah, I saw that and did look around. :) But alas, nodda yet.(I posted an update with both scopes showing) But see it says localstorage and session in the storage fields. May be a clue there?

Comment: The latest screen shot shows you on the "both" tab, which shows both local and session storage. No mystery there.

Comment: In Chrome I see it listed under the IndexedDB (not under local storage) but in Firefox am not seeing anywhere else to look for anything else besides what I see in Firestorage Plus. So mystery persists, at least to me LOL, where would you be looking?

Comment: First, I would make sure that through code (use the Console), I can retrieve a value. That will tell me if it's worth looking anywhere.  Just a side  question... Why are you using localForage and not localStorage?

Comment: I created this entire application in Chrome using localStorage, worked flawlessly, until I went to Firefox. Firefox has issues with localStorage so I went to their wrapper as a solution to get both browsers working with this code.

I will do a more thorough testing and see what I can set and get outright. I'll post any findings in a while. THANX much for the advice, Scott! ^5

Comment: What version of FF are you using? `localStorage` has pretty good support  in FF since version 3.5 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

Comment: 45.0.1, the latest version. I did not expect any surprises after reading the reviews of it being the go-to option, as well as it being a Firefox based wrapper. I am developing on a localized Intranet, perhaps that has something to do with it.

I started down the problem path when I ran into an issue with using "let" in Firefox. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637104/can-i-transpile-for-es6-es5-without-npm-vs-node-etc-and-just-the-js-code-its ) I was getting; "Error: let is a reserved identifier" and looked at this issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=738617

Comment: Set and Get work in both browsers, but it isn't showing up in my FF Dev console anywhere. Only in Chrome. Maybe Firestorage isn't what I should be using or where I should be looking, perhaps?

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to just use localStorage?

Comment: I believe it was due to having a problem using promises and the "let" keyword (Work has had me project-jumping so am straining to recall specifics) my goal was to utilize the local storage to alleviate server calls and traffic and ran into a situation where I needed promises to get data. That was wehen I ran into the "let" keyword problem. I also believe I had read that Firefox themselves had security concerns/issues with localStorage and may not standardize, but I cannot be sure as it's been a few months since I last worked on this thing. I would've preferred to have left it localStorage.

Comment: Interesting note; I used the "simple session detection" FF extension and it alerted me to only one 'setItem' event when several had executed. So I am thinking that this is not a domain-scope data-session retention, but a page by page blow, which severely limits the usefulness in my case.

BUT, yet it does get recorded and recalled. I am just going to forge ahead and do on the fly troubleshooting by putting the data info in the console. But the page-by-page scope seems a mostlikely cuplrit at this stage, at least to me. Just an FYI to see if you have any take on this.

Answer (score 0):

Extensions like Firestorage Plus! and simplesession are NOT reliable when looking for data being set with localForage!!! The key (pun intended) is to use the Firefox built-in Inspector.

I could NOT find this in my FF after adding extensions, but I had the FF Dev Edition, ran that, enabled the Storage tool in config options, and bam, there they ALL were!! Hope this helps someone else out.

I "believe" that if you set data on a different page/file, those extensions wont see these values, only the orginial file/page's getItem data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I am getting "No data present for selected host." I am confused, because I thought that localForage was developed for Firefox, but it doesn't seem to work with it.